# How to determine interactions between filters in different pages?

Tags: powerbi

I have a problem about my filters in power bi. I have 3 different pages and they have all same filters. In my first 2 pages, I want to be able to select "select all" option. For this, from format section and selection controls, I selected "select all". Its fine for my first two pages. But in the 3. page, I have to select just one option, therefore i made it "single selection" from selection controls. But when I made it single selection, first 2 pages are changed too. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the filters (slicers) are the same, then for the 3rd page you need to turn of sync slicers.

You can view the sync slicer settings by going to View -> Show -> Sync slicers which will open a new right hand side menu, showing you which slicers are set to sync across which pages.

For more information refer to the following article: [Slicers in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-slicers#sync-and-use-slicers-on-other-pages)